# Merge list of data.frames with list element name as factor in merged data frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame, like the following, where `location` is a factor and `sample` is some measurement sample:

```
  location sample
1      'A'   0.10
2      'A'   0.20
3      'A'   0.15
4      'B'   0.15
5      'B'   0.99
6      'B'   0.54
...
```

I have a function `ECCDFpts(df)`, where `df` is a data.frame, that returns a set of `<x,y>` points on the empirical CCDF of `df$sample`, like so:

```
    x     y
1 0.0  1.00
2 0.1  0.99
3 0.2  0.75
...
```

Note that the number of `<x,y>` points returned is "arbitrary".  There is *not* a one-to-one mapping between input samples and output `<x,y>` rows.

I would like to compute this CCDF data on a *per factor (e.g., location)* basis, yielding a data.frame like this:

```
  location    x    y
1      'A'  0.0  1.0
2      'A'  0.1  1.0
3      'A'  0.2  0.3
4      'B'  0.0  1.0
5      'B'  0.1  1.0
6      'B'  0.2  0.7
...
```

My current approach is to split the initial data frame on factor `location`:

```
eccdfs_by_factor <- by(data, data$location, ECCDFpts)
```

This yields a list of data.frames:

```
data$location: A
    x    y
1 0.0  1.0
2 0.1  1.0
3 0.2  0.3
-----------------
data$location: B
    x    y
1 0.0  1.0
2 0.1  1.0
3 0.2  0.7
```

I don't know how to merge or unsplit this back into my desired form, shown previously.  I want to merge such that the name of the elements (data.frames) in the list becomes a column factor in the combined data.frame.

**Solution:**

This is a classic split-apply-combine problem, apparently. The cleanest [solutions below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849064/merge-list-of-data-frames-with-list-element-name-as-factor-in-merged-data-frame/6849462#6849462) use the `plyr` package function `ddply(...)`to do both the splitting, applying, and combining in one line!  There's no need for the base `by` function I used above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one shot solution uses the `plyr` package. Since I don't know your ECDFpts function, I am going to write my own to illustrate the usage.

```
# DEFINE DUMMY DATA
mydata = data.frame(
  location = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3),
  sample   = runif(9)
)

# DEFINE DUMMY FUNCTION
myfunc = function(dat){
   x = dat - mean(dat)
   y = dat - median(dat)
   return(data.frame(x, y)) 
}

# USE PLYR TO APPLY FUNCTION BY LOCATION
library(plyr)
ans = ddply(mydata, .(location), transform, x = myfunc(sample)$x, 
         y = myfunc(sample)$y)

  location sample       x      y
1        A  0.911  0.3279  0.232
2        A  0.678  0.0958  0.000
3        A  0.159 -0.4237 -0.520
4        B  0.908  0.3096  0.048
5        B  0.860  0.2615  0.000
6        B  0.027 -0.5711 -0.833
7        C  0.745  0.0694  0.000
8        C  0.343 -0.3327 -0.402
9        C  0.939  0.2633  0.194
```

EDIT. As identified in the comments by @David, the code can be further simplified as

```
# DEFINE DUMMY FUNCTION
myfunc = function(dat){
   x = with(dat, sample - mean(sample))
   y = with(dat, sample - median(sample))
   return(data.frame(x, y)) 
}

ans = ddply(mydata, .(location), myfunc)

  location       x        y
1        A -0.0308 -0.00564
2        A -0.0251  0.00000
3        A  0.0559  0.08102
4        B -0.4985 -0.69084
5        B  0.3062  0.11392
6        B  0.1923  0.00000
7        C -0.2894 -0.31495
8        C  0.0255  0.00000
9        C  0.2639  0.23838
```

Comment: Perhaps my example didn't illustrate this clearly, but `myfunc`  (or in my case, `ECDFpts`) should return a different number of rows from the input data set.  That is, the input data for a location might be 100000 samples, but plotting the CCDF just requires just, for example, 50 `<x,y>` points.  Put another way, `ECCDFpt` does not yield a single output for each input sample; it yields an arbitrary number of rows that is independent of the number of sample. Thus, the output is not bindable to the original data.  There is not a map between a single `sample` and a `<x,y>` point.

Comment: @David B. that is relatively easy to fix. you just need to change the `transform` function inside `ddply` to `summarize` and that would do the trick. Check my edit. It is clean

Comment: @David. yes `plyr` is beautiful. whenever u have a problem that requires a `split-apply-combine` strategy, `plyr` is super-elegant. thanks to @Hadley.

Comment: I actually don't even need `summarize`.  Just `ans <- ddply(mydata, .(location), myfunc)` is sufficient.  This also saves both the multiple evaluations of `myfunc` and the need to know the output columns from `myfunc`. If you edit your solution to show this first (and then the transform/summarize methods, because others might find those useful), I'll accept your solution

Answer (score 5):

Update: If I understand what you want you correctly...

```
library(plyr)
ldply(your_data)
```

For example:

```
x <- list(a=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(2,3,4,5)),
          b=data.frame(x=c(4,3,2,1),y=c(5,4,3,2)))
ldply(x)

  .id x y
1   a 1 2
2   a 2 3
3   a 3 4
4   a 4 5
5   b 4 5
6   b 3 4
7   b 2 3
8   b 1 2
```

Comment: This is interesting, but encodes the attributes (x and y) via a column `variable`.  The attributes should be the column headings themselves, because many other functions won't be able handle the additional step of dereferencing `x` and `y` via the `variable` column.

Comment: That said, if you know how to easily go from the 'encoded' form to the dereferenced form I desire, please let me know!  If that's easy to do, this would be my currently preferred answer.

Comment: You're going to giggle when you see it.

Comment: It's way to easy to forget about the "other" ply's. ldply(), dlply(), d_ply(), l_ply().

Comment: `reshape::melt(x, id=1:2)` works too, and seems more efficient.

Comment: Gosh that's simple! I'm just hearing about the `plyr` package from the answers to this question (I'm very new to R).  This answers my literal question (merging the `by()` output), but Ramnath's answer lead to a one-liner using `ddply()` that does both the splitting/analyze (that the `by()` call did before) and the merge.

Comment: @Brandon Bertelsen it's `id.vars` in `melt.data.frame`, which is called by `melt.list`.

Answer (score 3):

The answers you've received are more than adequate, but for completeness I'd like to add a solution that explains how to get your desired result starting from your output from the `by` command. I'm going to use a slightly modified version of Ramnath's example for illustration:

```
mydata = data.frame(
  location = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3),
  sample   = runif(9)
)

# DEFINE DUMMY FUNCTION - slightly different from ramnath's
myfunc = function(dat){
    temp <- data.frame(x = runif(3), y = rnorm(3))
    return(temp) 
}
```

You're splitting the data by `location` and applying your function using `by`:

```
rs <- by(mydata,mydata$location,FUN = myfunc)

mydata$location: A
          x           y
1 0.2730105 -0.06923224
2 0.9354096 -0.18336131
3 0.6359926 -0.04054326
----------------------------------------------------------- 
mydata$location: B
          x           y
1 0.5621529 -0.26404739
2 0.8098687  0.07912883
3 0.7334650  0.38287794
----------------------------------------------------------- 
mydata$location: C
          x          y
1 0.8443924 -0.9055125
2 0.7922256  0.1757586
3 0.4923929 -0.1931579
```

Now, a very handy thing to know is that we can put everything back together again using `do.call` and `rbind`:

```
result <- do.call(rbind,rs)

            x           y
A.1 0.2730105 -0.06923224
A.2 0.9354096 -0.18336131
A.3 0.6359926 -0.04054326
B.1 0.5621529 -0.26404739
B.2 0.8098687  0.07912883
B.3 0.7334650  0.38287794
C.1 0.8443924 -0.90551251
C.2 0.7922256  0.17575858
C.3 0.4923929 -0.19315789
```

But wait, you say! What about adding my location column? Well, notice what `do.call(rbind,rs)` did to the row names of your result! We can add the location column by just extracting the first character from the row names:

```
result$location <- substr(row.names(result),1,1)
```

This assumes, of course, that your locations are coded using a single character. But in general, the resulting row names should be in the form `location.x`, so you could always `strsplit` or regular expressions to extract the location names.

Finally, you can always simply modify the function you apply to each piece to add the location name as a column before returning the result, like so:

```
#Output not shown
myfunc1 = function(dat){
    temp <- data.frame(x = runif(3), y = rnorm(3))
    temp$location <- dat$location[1]
    return(temp) 
}
rs1 <- by(mydata,mydata$location,FUN = myfunc1)
result1 <- do.call(rbind,rs1)
```

So you'd just have to modify your `ECCDFpts` function in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks for also adding your solution.  Ramnath's solution incorrectly assumed a one-to-one mapping between `samples` and `<x,y>` points and Brandon's solution requires an extra dereferencing step.  Yours addresses those two issues.  It's too bad though that the location has to be manually extracted from the row name.  I can always roll my own rbind that accepts a a name and value for an additional column, but this seems like it should be doable with built-in functions.

Comment: I'll use this solution for now, and if no one proposes a cleaner solution (i.e., no manual row.name string parsing) with in a couple of days, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: `substr`, `rbind`, etc *are* built-in functions! ;) Note that no row name string parsing is necessary *at all* in my last example. R will extend the location name to whatever length is necessary given the object you're about to return. It's literally a two line modification: on line in ECCDFpts and then the `do.call(...)`.

Comment: Yes, to be pedantic substr is a built-in function. ;)  But, have to manually parse the row.name requires knowing (and now dependent on) the row.name format.  It's a very roundabout way of doing things.  I may be the simplest via R builtins (i.e, not using `plyr`), but as a programmers it still feels dirty!

Comment: The biggest hassle with this approach is keeping track of the labels - that's one of the big advantages of plyr.